# Google Play error "No internet connection" but subscription purchased successfully problem

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am implementing Google in-app purchase in my app.

There is one case in which my app is not working properly.

These are the steps I followed:

1. User clicks on the **Buy** button in my app. (The app starts launch purchase flow)
2. Google Play dialog comes up with the **"Subscribe"** button.
3. The user clicks on the "Subscribe" button. Then immediately turns the internet off. The **Google Play dialog shows "No internet connection. Make sure ..." error**.
4. The dialog closes Google sends purchase **canceled response**.

Now my app thinks the purchase was canceled but when the user tries to purchase the subscription again the **Google play shows "You're already subscribed ..." error.**

How can I solve this problem?

Do I have to add any specific handling for this problem?

Thanks in advance geeks.

Comment: I take it that, if you run the same test, but leave the internet connection intact, you do not get a "You're already subscribed" error? That is, the subscribe is successful?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question properly. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm seeking to verify that, before you run the test, the subscription is truly in a "not purchased" state. If you can successfully subscribe when you have _do_ have a valid internet connection, then that must be the case.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that the subscription was in "not purchased" state before running the test from the Google Play app -> Subscriptions

Comment: I believe you, but allow me to point out that this is not equivalent to saying "the subscription buying process works correctly when the internet is connected". Your question indicates that it's the absence of an internet connection that causes Google Play to malfunction. Can you verify that Google Play works entirely as expected when the internet is available?

Comment: Yes, It is tested by our testing team. The purchase works fine when the internet connection is available.

Comment: Hmm. I would suggest creating a new subscription (just for testing purposes), to try and establish the conditions under which the device enters this state. For example, if the device has never ever (successfully) purchased that particular SKU, does the behavior occur?

Comment: Also, I just tried this on one of my own apps, and I cannot reproduce the behavior. Android 7.0

Comment: Can you give me your email address? I have a screencast of this problem.

Comment: This question was asked before one year but did not get any answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548649/android-in-app-purchase-while-purchasing-got-network-failed-popup-but-purchase

Comment: Please reference [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources) to share files.

Comment: Thanks @greeble31 for the link, I have uploaded the screencast on this link http://www.filedropper.com/kga1.

Comment: As you can see at the beginning of the screencast the Google Play allows the user to buy the subscription, which clearly indicates that the subscription was not already owned.

Comment: I have [moved this conversation to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182240/discussion-between-kishan-vaishnav-and-greeble31). (Not sure why I have to manually notify you of that...)